# PHP class called with jQuery $.post can't find extends class

Tags: php, jquery, inheritance, post

I'm trying to instanciate a inherited class *Popup* using jQuery $.post

```
$("#tableInscrits").on("click", "i", function() {
       var mId=($(this).attr('name'));
       $.post('pages/controleurs/Popup.php',{Id:mId,Action:"read",View:"PopupAuto"},function(data) {
```

If Popup class is not inherited, it succeds.
But this fails :

```
class Popup extends Controleurs {
...
}
```

In /var/log/apache2/error.log :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Controleurs' not found in /<PATH_TO>/Popup.php on line 10, referer: <URL>
```

*Controleurs* exists, as i use it in another inherited class (where i call the $.post method)

*autoload* is up-to-date by *composer.phar update*.

I tried to create a fork (*ControleursII*), but it failed too

Any suggestions ?

EDIT :
When you call $.post, include_path and magic constants changes. So, if you called a php which refers to another php etc ... it's cascading fails. My experience is you can only call ONE php file which works standalone, with no include or require. Waste of time.

Comment: Is `Controleurs` included in `Popup.php` though

Comment: require_once '/path/to/ParentClass.php`;

Comment: Thank you ! 
including the abstract class and his interface works. But i don't understand why i have to : in the others inherited class i don't have this includes. I thought *composer* do it.

Comment: is it your own parent class?

Comment: Yes. Controleurs is an abstract class. Controleurs implements IControleurs. Both class are in their own file on server.